# method cannot be applied to given types / cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, invocation

I can't seem to get past this error. My code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Collector {

    public static void Names () {

        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user to enter the number of students
    System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
    int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();

    // Create arrays
    String[] names = new String[numberOfStudents];
    double[] scores = new double[numberOfStudents];

    // Enter student name and score
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
        {
      System.out.print("Enter student's name: ");
      names[i] = input.next();
      System.out.print("Enter student's exam score: ");
      scores[i] = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.println(" ");
          }

    }
      void SortRoutine (String[] names, double[] scores) {
            for (int i = scores.length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
      // Find the maximum in the scores[0..i]
      double currentMax = scores[0];
      int currentMaxIndex = 0;

      for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
      {
        if (currentMax < scores[j])
        {
          currentMax = scores[j];
          currentMaxIndex = j;
        }
      }

      //arrange values as necessary 
      if (currentMaxIndex != i)
      {
        scores[currentMaxIndex] = scores[i];
        scores[i] = currentMax;
        String temp = names[currentMaxIndex];
        names[currentMaxIndex] = names[i];
        names[i] = temp;


      }
    }

   // Print student data
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("*****   Student Scores Sorted High to Low   *****");
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (int i = scores.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      System.out.println(names[i] + "\t" + scores[i] + "\t");
    }
      System.out.println(" ");
    }
  }
```

Main Method:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.Arrays;
public class NameCollector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collector collect = new Collector();
    collect.Names();
    collect.SortRoutine();
    }
}
```

If I remove the arguments from line 28 of the Collector class I get `cannot find symbol errors`. Which I believe means that Jcreator can't find the array values. How would I go about making the array values defined in my first method visible to the second? If I leave the arguments in line 28 the error message is:

```
C:\Users\Dark Prince\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\NameCollector\src\NameCollector.java:16: error: method SortRoutine in class Collector cannot be applied to given types;
collect.SortRoutine();
       ^
  required: String[],double[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Process completed.

I'm thinking I should not use the arguments and make it so the array values can be seen by the sorting method, but really I just want the darn thing to work.

Comment: what packages do the two classes reside in?

Answer (score 0):

You asked: *How would I go about making the array values defined in my first method visible to the second?*

There's plenty of ways to do this. This is one way of doing it (probably not the best):

You can turn the arrays into static instance members in the Collector class like this:

```
public class Collector {

    static String[] names;
    static double[] scores;

    public static void Names () {
```

And then when you create the arrays in the Names method you'd do this:

```
// Create arrays
names = new String[numberOfStudents];
scores = new double[numberOfStudents];
```

And finally you change the method signature for SortRoutine from:

```
void SortRoutine (String[] names, double[] scores)
```

to

```
void SortRoutine ()
```

Comment: Ah I see, I had attempted making the arrays static, but I was declaring them in the method, not the class. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @MaxwellBell If my answer solver your problem please consider accepting it.